# Divi - custom Map module

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I've tried to edit the existing Map module's styles to get another Map theme instead of the default one, but Divi doesn't seem to offer that feature.

Example of the mentioned styles:

```
    center: {
        lat: 40.674,
        lng: -73.945
    },
    zoom: 12,
    styles: [{
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#8754c4"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "gamma": 0.01
        }, {
            "lightness": 20
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": -31
        }, {
            "lightness": -33
        }, {
            "weight": 2
        }, {
            "gamma": 0.8
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 30
        }, {
            "saturation": 30
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "on"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": 20
        }, {
            "visibility": "on"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#8945c7"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 20
        }, {
            "saturation": -20
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": 10
        }, {
            "saturation": -30
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "saturation": 25
        }, {
            "lightness": 25
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
        }, {
            "visibility": "on"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#ffffff"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }, {
            "color": "#ff0000"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
            "visibility": "off"
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [{
            "lightness": -20
        }]
    }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
            "color": "#7950a9"
        }]
    }]
```

How would I go about applying these styles to the existing Map module? Is there an external plugin for this feature?

https://elegantmarketplace.com/downloads/divi-map-extended-module/

This paid module adds these features, but I'm wondering if there's another way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

you can add your custom style in this file:

```
/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/scripts/frontend-builder-scripts.js
```

Line 2405, replace this:

```
                $this_map_container.data('map', new google.maps.Map( $this_map[0], {
                    zoom: parseInt( $this_map.attr('data-zoom') ),
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat( $this_map.attr('data-center-lat') ) , parseFloat( $this_map.attr('data-center-lng') )),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    scrollwheel: $this_map.attr('data-mouse-wheel') == 'on' ? true : false,
                    draggable: is_draggable,
                    panControlOptions: {
                        position: $this_map_container.is( '.et_beneath_transparent_nav' ) ? google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM : google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                    },
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        position: $this_map_container.is( '.et_beneath_transparent_nav' ) ? google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM : google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                    },
                    styles: [ {
                        stylers: [
                            { saturation: parseInt( this_map_grayscale ) }
                        ]
                    } ]
                }));
```

with this:

```
    $this_map_container.data('map', new google.maps.Map( $this_map[0], {
                    zoom: parseInt( $this_map.attr('data-zoom') ),
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat( $this_map.attr('data-center-lat') ) , parseFloat( $this_map.attr('data-center-lng') )),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    scrollwheel: $this_map.attr('data-mouse-wheel') == 'on' ? true : false,
                    draggable: is_draggable,
                    panControlOptions: {
                        position: $this_map_container.is( '.et_beneath_transparent_nav' ) ? google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM : google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                    },
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        position: $this_map_container.is( '.et_beneath_transparent_nav' ) ? google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM : google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                    },
                    styles: [{
                        "featureType": "all",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "color": "#8754c4"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "all",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "gamma": 0.01
                        }, {
                            "lightness": 20
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "all",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "saturation": -31
                        }, {
                            "lightness": -33
                        }, {
                            "weight": 2
                        }, {
                            "gamma": 0.8
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "all",
                        "elementType": "labels.icon",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "administrative",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "color": "#ffffff"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "administrative",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "landscape",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "lightness": 30
                        }, {
                            "saturation": 30
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "landscape",
                        "elementType": "labels.text",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "landscape",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "on"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "saturation": 20
                        }, {
                            "visibility": "on"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "color": "#8945c7"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "poi.park",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "lightness": 20
                        }, {
                            "saturation": -20
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "lightness": 10
                        }, {
                            "saturation": -30
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "saturation": 25
                        }, {
                            "lightness": 25
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "color": "#ffffff"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "labels.text",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "color": "#ffffff"
                        }, {
                            "visibility": "on"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "color": "#ffffff"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }, {
                            "color": "#ff0000"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "transit",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "transit",
                        "elementType": "labels.text",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "transit",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "visibility": "off"
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "lightness": -20
                        }]
                    }, {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [{
                            "color": "#7950a9"
                        }]
                    }]

                }));
```

Comment: Be ware it can be overwritten when the theme is updated.

Answer (score 0):

it dosent work to me so far, now that piece of code is in the 2499 line and looks like this:

```
$this_map_container.data('map', new google.maps.Map( $this_map[0], {
                        zoom: parseInt( $this_map.attr('data-zoom') ),
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat( $this_map.attr('data-center-lat') ) , parseFloat( $this_map.attr('data-center-lng') )),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        scrollwheel: $this_map.attr('data-mouse-wheel') == 'on' ? true : false,
                        draggable: is_draggable,
                        panControlOptions: {
                            position: $this_map_container.is( '.et_beneath_transparent_nav' ) ? google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM : google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                        },
                        zoomControlOptions: {
                            position: $this_map_container.is( '.et_beneath_transparent_nav' ) ? google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM : google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                        },
                        styles: [ {
                            stylers: [
                                { saturation: parseInt( this_map_grayscale ) }
                            ]
                        } ]
                    }));
```

and the style I'm trying to set up is this:

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212121"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#212121"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#313131"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#d900d9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#181818"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#1b1b1b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#a71089"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#600659"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#373737"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#af1498"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5a9ea"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#3c3c3c"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e72ecb"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#4e4e4e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5a9ea"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#3d3d3d"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

how should I do it?

Answer (score -1):

You can try the plugin **Snazzy Map** for colormap in divi,its easy to handle
Plugin  [LINK](https://wordpress.org/plugins/snazzy-maps/)

You can also visit the main site [Snazzy map](https://snazzymaps.com/)

If you use this plugin , then it dose not overwrite with theme update. Thanks